# "handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy" when starting and Activity from a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to make an app with firestore. Right now i'm trying to show a list with some summed up info and when you click on it I want to show the full info in a new Activity.

I have the list working fine with a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and i'm trying to do the new Activity. But the activity shows a blank screen.

I've tried with the click listener directly in the ViewHolder and also using and interface that I pass on the constructor.

I also tried not passing any entra on the Intent and the result is always the same.

```
class CalendarEventHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textFechas;
    private TextView textPlazas;

    CalendarEventHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textFechas = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_hora);
        textPlazas = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_plazas);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Clase clase = FirestoreEntityFactory.getEntity(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), Clase.class);
               /* if (listener != null) {
                    listener.clickItem(clase);
                }*/

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("clase", clase);

                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), AsistenciasActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The result is a blank screen and a warning messages that says:

```
handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@e14f85
```